# log4net ADO Stored Procedure

Tags: log4net

I am trying to call an existing Stored Procedure but can't get it to log. Seems to be parameter type conversion problem, but I can't figure it out.

Error on build is:

> log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property
>   [conversionPattern] to set object on
>   [log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout]

web.config is:

```xml
<appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <threshold value="ALL"/>
  <param name="ConnectionType" value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <param name="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=central-db.canterbury.ac.uk\devel;Initial Catalog=SourceDB;Persist Security Info=True;/>
  <param name="UseTransactions" value="False" />
  <commandText value="dbo.usperrLogError" />
  <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@ApplicationId"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="2" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
      <key value="EventGuid" />
      <conversionPattern value="%property{APP-ID}"/>
      </layout>
  </parameter>
  //
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@EventGuid"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
      <key value="EventGuid" />
      <conversionPattern value="%property{GUID}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
```

Am setting Properties like this:

```cs
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["GUID"] = eventGuid.ToString();
```

Following the log4net debug error there is an additional error here:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] Failed in DoAppend
System.ArgumentNullException: Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.get_Item(Object key)
   at log4net.Util.PropertiesDictionary.get_Item(String key) in c:\work\svn_root\apache\log4net\tags\log4net-1.2.10-rc2\build\package\log4net-1.2.10\src\Util\PropertiesDictionary.cs:line 114
   at log4net.Core.LoggingEvent.LookupProperty(String key) in c:\work\svn_root\apache\log4net\tags\log4net-1.2.10-rc2\build\package\log4net-1.2.10\src\Core\LoggingEvent.cs:line 1404
   at log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout.Format(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) in c:\work\svn_root\apache\log4net\tags\log4net-1.2.10-rc2\build\package\log4net-1.2.10\src\Layout\RawPropertyLayout.cs:line 84
   at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter.FormatValue(IDbCommand command, LoggingEvent loggingEvent) in c:\work\svn_root\apache\log4net\tags\log4net-1.2.10-rc2\build\package\log4net-1.2.10\src\Appender\AdoNetAppender.cs:line 1117
   at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(IDbTransaction dbTran, LoggingEvent[] events) in c:\work\svn_root\apache\log4net\tags\log4net-1.2.10-rc2\build\package\log4net-1.2.10\src\Appender\AdoNetAppender.cs:line 560
   at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events) in c:\work\svn_root\apache\log4net\tags\log4net-1.2.10-rc2\build\package\log4net-1.2.10\src\Appender\AdoNetAppender.cs:line 501
   at log4net.Appender.BufferingAppenderSkeleton.Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) in c:\work\svn_root\apache\log4net\tags\log4net-1.2.10-rc2\build\package\log4net-1.2.10\src\Appender\BufferingAppenderSkeleton.cs:line 463
   at log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) in c:\work\svn_root\apache\log4net\tags\log4net-1.2.10-rc2\build\package\log4net-1.2.10\src\Appender\AppenderSkeleton.cs:line 316
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] Failed in DoAppend
System.ArgumentNullException: Key cannot be null.
```

Clearly I am not using `RawPropertyLayout` correctly but can't find good examples!

Answer (score 3):

I do something like you, but I use the `log4net.Layout.PatternLayout` like this:

```xml
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@ProjectParam1"/>
  <dbType value="String"/>
  <size value="254" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%property{OrderNumber}" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
```

If I understand the `log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout` correctly, you have to use it as follows:

```xml
<parameterName value="@EventGuid"/>
   <dbType value="String"/>
   <size value="50" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
      <param name="Key" value="GUID" />
   </layout>
</parameter>
```

Comment: Oops. Apologies for the typo in the web.config. Should be : <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@ApplicationId"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="2" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
          <key value="ApplicationId" />
          <conversionPattern value="%property{APP-ID}"/>
          </layout>
      </parameter> Thanks for the response but WHY do I have the build error - what's it looking for ? My understanding is that I must use RawPropertyLayout if I want to pass parameters at INT column data-types. Correct ?

Comment: I am not sure why it is a "build" error, but have a look how I made the configuration with the RawPropertyLayout class. I think this class is used when you do not need or want a conversion e.g. if you want to pass an int to an INT column.

Comment: Thanks Stefan - Unfortunately - the same problem still exists.

Comment: log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property [conversionPattern] to set object on [log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout]

Comment: Followed by : A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] Failed in DoAppend
System.ArgumentNullException: Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.get_Item(Object key)

Comment: Here is what I have used :<parameter>
      <parameterName value="@EventGuid"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
         <size value="50" />
         <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
           <param name="Key" value="GUID" />
           <conversionPattern value="%property{GUID}"/>
        </layout>
     </parameter>

Comment: Maybe you have a pointer to a config that : Calls a SP, uses a GUID as a key and passes parameters to be stored as INT ? Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: you need to remove the conversionPattern element. when you look at my version you see that there is no such thing...

Comment: Thanks for that Stefan - There is Progress: No more log4net errors but no row inserted yet. One of the table columns is defined as BIT and I have the following error :

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] Failed in DoAppend
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Error converting data type nvarchar to bit.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)

Comment: I have tried using a Dbtype of Boolean but that is not valid. Unfortunately I am, unable to change the SP. Is there any other type that I can use that is compatible with BIT ?

Comment: @ApplicationId INT,
 @SourceKey NVARCHAR(2000),
 @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @ErrorNumber INT,
 @ErrorSeverity INT,
 @ErrorState INT,
 @ErrorLocation NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @ErrorUserId NVARCHAR(256),
 @ErrorExtraInfo NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @ErrorCreationDate DATETIME,
 @Debug BIT,
 @DebugInfo VARCHAR(MAX),
 @EventGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
 @CodeVersion VARCHAR(20),
 @ErrorType VARCHAR(5),
 @UserAdditionalInfo NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: OK - Aplogies - Using the following stops the errors : <dbType value="Boolean"/>
         <size value="1" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
          <!--<conversionPattern value="%property{DEBUG}"/>-->
          <param name="Key" value="DEBUG" />

Comment: But - STILL No row inserted !

Comment: and Now........... Rows are Inserted. Apologies - DBAs tell me there was a delay in the insert due to a problem with SQL-Server. Would like to thank you once again Stefan for your most valuable assistance.